# Assign privileges to a postgres user

Tags: postgresql, amazon-rds, aws-aurora

I am working on creating a postgres user and assign certain privileges to the user. These are privileges to execute certain functions with the end goal of being able to replicate data or change-data-capture.

Specifically, I am looking at the `system privilege` column of the postgres row in the table - https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonRDS/latest/UserGuide/UsingWithRDS.MasterAccounts.html

I am running into issues granting execute privileges here. For example -
`grant execute on routine pg_terminate_backend() to <db_user>;`

This returns an error - `function pg_terminate_backend() does not exist` However, I am able to query it in `information_schema.routines` table.

What would be the right to grant the privileges to a db user. I tried creation of a role and grant privileges but it shows the same error.

Comment: For PostgreSQL, the solution would be membership in `pg_signal_backend`. I cannot tell about Amazon's fork.